# I have to move negative elements at end of array and in some cases like provided below I'm getting a garbage vale instead of negative element

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 10
int main()
{
    //code
    int n,i=0,arr[MAX];
    cin>>n;
    for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    int j=1;
    while(i<n&&j<=n)
    {
        if(arr[i]>0)
        {   
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    else if(arr[i]<0 && arr[j]>0)
    {
        int temp=arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[j];
        arr[j]=temp;
        i++;
    }
    else if(arr[i]<0 && arr[j]<0)
    {
        j++;
    }
    else 
    {
        i++;
    }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

INPUT

```
    4
    -8
    -6
    7
    8
```

OUTPUT

```
    7 8 4196864 -6
```

How can I resolve this?

I have to move negative elements at end of array and in some cases like provided below I'm getting a garbage value instead of negative element. Some cases are working but many are not specially the ones with two consecutive negative elements with following positive element.

Comment: [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition)?

Comment: You need to learn how to use a debugger and step through your code.

Comment: `j <=n ` is suspicious...

Comment: Quick note: as you have posted C++ code, rather than C, you would be well advised to `#include <csdtio>` instead of `#include <stdio.h>`, but further, as you never actually use any of that functionality and instead use `iostream` you can remove that include entirely.

Comment: `std::partition(arr, arr + n, [&](int val){return val >= 0; });` -- This single line of code does the job of your entire program.

Comment: *How can I resolve this?* -- Junk the code and do something [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20a48624c68e63e3)

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've posted, it looks like you are using C, but with `cout` and `cin` borrowed from C++.

As PaulMcKenzie already posted a one-line C++ solution, here is how you would write it *your way* (the C way):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

void move_neg_to_end(int *arr, int n)
{
    int start, end = n-1;
    for (start = 0; start <= end; start++) {
        if (arr[start] >= 0)
            continue;

        while (start < end && arr[end] < 0)
            end--;

        if (start >= end)
            break;
        
        swap(&arr[start], &arr[end]);
        end--;
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```c
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {4, -8, -6, 7, 8, -3, 2};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);

    move_neg_to_end(arr, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Here is what's wrong with your code:

**1-** Don't mix `<stdio>` and `<iostream>`. You are using either C or C++, not both. So just choose one of them. If you are using C++ (your case), then go for `<iostream>`.

**2-** Avoid `using namespace std` because it pollutes the global namespace. Use `std::` prefix instead, or if you want "shortcuts" `using std::cin`.

**3-** Avoid macros like `#define MAX 10` and use `const int max = 10` instead. Macros make debugging a pain.

**4-** In C++ use `std::array` or `std::vector`. Avoid raw arrays.

**5-** `cin >> n`... what if `n` exceeds `MAX`?

**6-** `j <= n` causes your array to overflow.

**7-** The logic of your code is wrong. `j` should start from `n-1`, not from `0`. Here is how you can do it:

1. If `arr[i] >= 0` go to the next element.
2. If `arr[i] < 0` and `arr[j] < 0` then keep decrementing `j` until it finds a positive element or is lesser than or equal to `i`.
3. If `arr[i] < 0` and `arr[j] >= 0` then swap `arr[i]` and `arr[j]`.
4. Goto step 1 if `i <= j`.

Comment: Can you please give a few minutes to view my code and tell me where was I wrong ? I will be really thankful..

Comment: @Arpita I've edited my answer. Consider upvoting & accepting if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is posted for anyone looking for a C++ solution using algorithm functions.  The function that gets the job done is [std::partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#define MAX 10
int main()
{
    int n = 4;
    int arr[MAX] = {-8, -6, 7, 8};
    std::partition(arr, arr + n, [&](int val) { return val >= 0;});
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
       std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
8 7 -6 -8
```

If you want to keep the original, relative order of the elements, you can use [std::stable_partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#define MAX 10
int main()
{
    int n = 4;
    int arr[MAX] = {-8, -6, 7, 8};
    std::stable_partition(arr, arr + n, [&](int val) { return val >= 0;});
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
       std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
7 8 -8 -6
```

Comment: Thanks .. I m a beginner.. I didn't know about this..